# How to make a TreeView in DevExpress?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem in revealing my data in treeview. I want to use a dataset to make an automatic childnode for the treeview. I want two columns 1st col is were the name of the payment then the other is for payment.

How can i do that? Please help me.
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

A treeview is more for a hierarchical structure, with child and parent nodes. It sounds like you need more of a table, which can be done more easily with a DataGridView.

Comment: Can you please give me a sample for me to guide?